# Printer Lazy Datatable in Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I use lazy datatable in primefaces. I want to use printer components but only first page is printed because of lazy datatable. What do I need printing all pages?

Comment: Printer prints what is visible... If you want more, either use the exporter and have the client print that document or have the page reload, show all records and print that.

Comment: When page reload and then print, process is too longer, but exporting data takes too short time. Why is this happening?

Comment: Actually, he explains it here. User manual page 396 "Printer is sending a specific JSF component to the printer, not the whole page." You can use Ireport for reporting